# why is orchard throwing an error with the app data folder

Tags: orchardcms, file-permissions, orchardcms-1.6, app-data

Created a module and ran it. All worked fine. Copied over a few files from an existing project to save writing out the registration forms again.

Ran the application but now it wont work. From debug, error comes from starter.cs it says:

```
// Previous initialization resulted in an error (and another initialization is running)
            if (_previousError != null) {
                throw new ApplicationException("Error during application initialization", _previousError);
            }
```

When I run CTRL+F5 it says:

> App_Data\Dependencies\Orchard.ContentPermissions.dll' is denied.

From googling I've found that this issue seems to be related to uploading the website to the dev server.

How can I resolve it?

I have tried closing and re-opening Visual Studio. Restarting the ASP.NET dev server, and deleting the cache file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have writing permissions on app_data and all subfolders for the user under which the app pool runs.

Comment: thanks for the reply I had to re-start my laptop. that seemed to fix the problem